# Is there an app to stream torrent videos?

Tags: android, media-player, bittorrent

I need an app that works like Popcorn Time, but Popcorn Time is limited to the movies it gives you, I'd like an app that I can input a torrent file url and it will stream the video.
I'm actually using MX Player to stream videos, but it doesn't support torrent.
Any recommendations?

Comment: Isn't it the same as this http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10927/torrent-http-proxy-with-seek-support ?

Comment: Popcorn Time uses [Peerflix](https://github.com/mafintosh/peerflix) to stream torrents…

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called [Joker.org](http://joker.org/). It was live for a while but after a ton of press they are currently seeking a new home. They had to shut down due to pressure from copyright holders however they are planning to return. You can sign up on their website to stay up to date on their progress.

> Joker.org is a service that converts your torrent files into streamable videos. Easy as pie.