# Torrent client with continuous file download

Tags: windows, desktop-client, bittorrent

I'm searching for a torrent client with following features:

- Continuously download a file (so video files can be viewed while downloading)
- Prioritize first and last piece of a file (without last piese some videos cannot be seeked)
- Windows support

Optional features:

- Download files in selected order
- Rehash only selected files in a torrent
- Search in torrent/file names (I had >1k torrents)
- Linux version preferable (I have a Linux NAS)

Clients I already tested:

- µTorrent 2 - continuous downloading can be turned on with a hack, but no way to prioritize last piece. MKV files cannot be seeked with a hardware player then. Files can be only downloaded by order they are listed in the torrent file.
- µTorrent 3 - IMO even continuous download haven't worked well. Still need a hack to turn continuuos downloading on.
- qBittorrent - can continuously download a file and prioritize first and last piece, but you must select it for every torrent. No idea how to download files in selected order. I don't like the program itself though. Added: it just failed on downloading the last piece of a file although all peers I was downloading from were seeds.

Comment: "I don't like the program itself though" <- Say why

Comment: @NicolasRaoul it's gui suxx, it's too simple and doesn't look good. uT3 looks prettier

Comment: what is continuous downloading compared to regular downloading? and what is the benefit of getting the first and last piece as quickly as possible?

Comment: @ycomp download a file from beginning to the end instead of random order. See qBittorrent.

Comment: ah, I guess contiguous downloading would be a better term for that. Continuous is a bit confusing. I guess that could be useful for watching a video before it completes, like streaming. Maybe that's the only use for it? streaming media?

Comment: @ycomp yes, exactly that's why.

Comment: Can you tell us why you want to do do this? And will you accept *only* a torrent solution?

Comment: @Mawg see comment of ycomp

Answer (score 1):

Please note, first of all, that this practice is not encouraged, per Bittorrent etiquette. More here: [link](http://wiki.vuze.com/w/Sequential_downloading_is_bad).

However, [qBittorrent](http://www.qbittorrent.org/) allows, once you started a torrent download, to right-click on it and request both sequential order download, as well as to download the first and last piece first. Hope I understood what your requirements are.

Comment: 1. I already mentioned qBittorrent in my answer, but continious download haven't worked always. Imagine I invited a friend to watch a movie, but instead of watching it we have to wait until it fully downloads because qbt fails again. 2. Link you gave is crap a) I don't understand quite how the authors come to this conclusion; b) on trackers I use most peers after initial seeding are seeds so it doesn't matter in which order to download.

Answer (score 1):

[Deluge](http://deluge-torrent.org/) is free and open source, has a Windows version and has an option for prioritizing first and last pieces in its settings.

It can be configured to download only one torrent at a time, and then you can reorder the torrents to choose which one to download first.

It's cross platform (Python based) and it's a client-server app, so you install the daemon on your NAS and then [configure the Windows app](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/ThinClient#GTKUI) to act as a client; you can of course use the Windows client as a stand-alone app as well; there is also a web UI that you can install on your NAS to interact without any kind of client.

Comment: Can it continiously download files?